# Header with image rmarkdown

Tags: r, header, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm new to Rmarkdown, how do I build a header like this? Only "AECOM" is just an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfLLg.png)

```
title: "Anexo 2 – Condições de cultivo e peso das amostras"
author: "AECOM"
format:
  pdf:
    papersize: A3
    latex_engine: tinytex
    classoption: landscape
execute:
  echo: false
  df-print: kable
editor: visual
params:
  tipo: tipo
geometry: "a3paper,left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=4cm, landscape"
header-includes:
```